# What is wrong with this C++ code? It crashes on run

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

I would like to know what is wrong with the following C++ code. It crashes on Run.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
        int info;
        node *addr;

        node(){
            info = 0;
            addr = NULL;          
        }

        ~node(){}
};

void func(node *);


int main(void){   
    node *head;
    node b;

    b.info = 10;

    *head = b;

    func(head); 
    getch();
}

void func(node *obj){
    cout<<"i: "<<(*obj).info;
}
```

Comment: the problem persists even replacing `cout<<"i: "<<(*obj).info;` with `cout<<"i: "<<(obj->info);` in the `func(node *)` function

Comment: You must allocate your class, I.e b = new node(), and then access element such as b->info = 10

Comment: `*head = b;` should be `head = &b;`

Comment: When a program crashes for you, your first reaction should be to run the program in a debugger. It will help you locate _where_ the crash is, and also let you examine variables to help you understand _why_ it crashed.

Comment: Isn't b = `new node()` equivalent to `node b;` ??

Comment: The expression `new node()` returns a pointer to a node dynamically allocated (presumably on the heap). `node b` is is an actual node object, rather than a pointer. They are very similar, in that both create storage for your node object, but they are 2 separate data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*head = b;
```

is not correct since head doesn't point to anything

```
head = &b ;
```

should solve the problem

Comment: note that `b` is a stack object, so `head` isn't valid after the function finishes.  Of course, `head` is also limited to `main()`, but it's not a safe thing to do while learning.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with

```
*head = b;
```

Replace it with

```
head = &b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's wrong is you've declared a pointer here:

```
node *head;
```

and then used it here:

```
 *head = b;
```

without allocating memory for `head`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `*head = b;` should instead be `head = &b;`, assuming you want to assign the address of `b` to the pointer `head`.

The bad version compiles but it would have assigned a copy of the object `b` to the address contained in an *uninitialized* pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your writing-to-arbitrary-memory problem, but I'd like to concentrate on some other things, such as:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

What's wrong with this is that you're using a compiler that is *heavily* out of date. C++ headers no longer have `.h` on them, and `conio.h` is severely non-standard and aged.

I would suggest first up that you update to a more recent environment.

In addition, one of the cornerstones of OO is that objects are responsible for their own actions. It is almost *never* a good idea for code to reach inside of an object to access members directly.

You should provide proper getters and setters and generally ensure that the only *public* stuff in your class is functions rather than data.

In other words, something like:

```
class node {
    public:
        node () {
            info = 0;
            addr = NULL;          
        }

        ~node() {
        }

        int getInfo() {
            return info;
        }
        void setInfo (int newInfo) {
            // Check newInfo for validity first.
            info = newInfo;
        }

        node *getAddr() {
            return addr;
        }
        void setAddr (node *newAddr) {
            // Check newAddr for validity first.
            addr = newAddr;
        }

    private:
        int info;
        node *addr;

};
```

Comment: I agree with you on both points, but find myself more and more using POD style structs in simple situations. If you are creating a library used by thousands of programmers world-wide, it's one thing, but if you are writing some simple logging util used by you and 3 or 10 other people in a smaller software shop, it actually saves time and energy just having a 'mOutputFile' handle, rather than a 'GetOutputFile()' function. Just my personal opinion after some time working professionally.

Comment: @Rollie, if everything is public, you may as well use struct and save a line of code :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: THANK YOU very much for this valuable information..evidently I am yet to learn the latest programming standards... I have been taught to use the conio.h since high school..
and I was not able to get out of it..

Would you please kind enough to point me to resources on programming styles that you feel I should adopt?

Comment: @paxdiablo I agree, and do :P it seems somewhat silly to me that they bother having 'class' and 'struct' in c++, and that there is a template parameter type 'class', which is somewhat confusing for beginners, whereas 'typename' is a bit more explicit.

Comment: @Jugesh, it's not so much programming style as following the standards as closely as possible (assuming you're interested in portability of code - if all you're ever going to do is Microsoft stuff, then portability could be a secondary concern). `comio` harkens back to the heydays of Borland/Inprise/Encilada (or whatever they call themselves nowadays) and most people use it just for `getch` (when there's a perfectly good `getchar` in the standard).

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. you reference an uninialized pointer  `*head`
2. you store a stack variable in a pointer.

I (like others) think when you say `*head = b`  you really mean `head = &b`.  In the first case, you reference a node pointer and assign a node value on top of it.  That's an error because the `head` variable hasn't been initialized, so you're copying a full node value on top of an invalid memory address.

If you replace with `head = &b`, it's slightly better, because now you set the `head` pointer to the address of `b`.  But now you hit the other error, since `b` is a stack variable, a pointer there would be valid only during the lifetime of the function.  As soon as the function finishes, the stack space will be reused and the `head` pointer would wreck anything there.

The typical solution is to keep `head` as a pointer to a node, but change `b` to a pointer to node too, and initialize it with a heap memory allocation, like `b = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node);`, or `b = new node;`.  Then you can store anything in `*b`, and at the end, store the pointer to a longer-lived variable, like `heap=b;`.